# Using regex to recognize patterns and clean data in pandas columns

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a dataset that contains innovation data of companies, by using some regex, I want to retrieve the licence data

```
company licences/patents
1       UX226, licence-pp-zz, licence-zz-pp, licence-xx-tt
2       VV3346E, SS345
3       licence-dd-zz
4       UT223, licence, ss
5       XBTYU, licence-tt-kk, licence-ss-tt
6       xc, zz
7       licence-xb-xz
```

Desired output:

```
company licences/patents                                    licence
1       UX226, licence-pp-zz, licence-zz-pp, licence-xx-tt  licence-pp-zz, licence-zz-pp, licence-xx-tt 
2       VV3346E, SS345
3       licence-dd-zz                                       licence-dd-zz
4       UT223, licence, ss
5       XBTYU, licence-tt-kk, licence-ss-tt                 licence-tt-kk, licence-ss-tt
6       xc, zz
7       licence-xb-xz                                       licence-xb-xz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['licence'] = df['licences/patents'].str.extractall('(licence-\w{2}-\w{2})')\
  .unstack().apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   company                                   licences/patents                                      licence
0        1  UX226, licence-pp-zz, licence-zz-pp, licence-x...  licence-pp-zz, licence-zz-pp, licence-xx-tt
1        2                                     VV3346E, SS345                                          NaN
2        3                                      licence-dd-zz                                licence-dd-zz
3        4                                 UT223, licence, ss                                          NaN
4        5                XBTYU, licence-tt-kk, licence-ss-tt                 licence-tt-kk, licence-ss-tt
5        6                                             xc, zz                                          NaN
6        7                                      licence-xb-xz                                licence-xb-xz
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, using [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and [`Series.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['licence'] = df['licences/patents'].str.findall(r'(licence[^,]*)').str.join(', ')
```

[out]

```
   company                                   licences/patents  \
0        1  UX226, licence-pp-zz, licence-zz-pp, licence-x...   
1        2                                     VV3346E, SS345   
2        3                                      licence-dd-zz   
3        4                                 UT223, licence, ss   
4        5                XBTYU, licence-tt-kk, licence-ss-tt   
5        6                                             xc, zz   
6        7                                      licence-xb-xz   

                                       licence  
0  licence-pp-zz, licence-zz-pp, licence-xx-tt  
1                                               
2                                licence-dd-zz  
3                                      licence  
4                 licence-tt-kk, licence-ss-tt  
5                                               
6                                licence-xb-xz
```

Answer (score 1):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/SLPlFe/1) might help you to create one group, `$1`, where your desired output may be:

```
(licence-[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})
```

[image: RegEx]

Answer (score 1):

`df['license'] = df['licences/patents'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(re.findall('lice.*',x)))`

It will create new column license with licenses stripped from original column.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

`df['licences/patents'].str.findall('(licence-[\w\-]+)').apply(", ".join)`